# Change password hashing to PBKDF2 on Debian-based OS

Tags: debian, security, password

I'm looking for a way to change the hashing scheme on my Debian-based OS from `sha512` to `pbkdf2`.

Searching the internet hasn't helped much. The closest I've got is this question: [Enable Blowfish-based Hash Support for Crypt](https://serverfault.com/questions/10585/enable-blowfish-based-hash-support-for-crypt/11685)

However, as `pbkdf2` is not Blowfish-based, I'm back to square one.

Comment: I'm not aware of one, but do note that the standard “SHA-512” scheme is *not* SHA-512(password+salt) or the like, but an iterated scheme using SHA-512 for its per-iteration transformation, with a design similar to PBKDF2. I'm not aware of a weakness of that scheme compared with PBKDF2.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still of interest to you, given how much time passed by since you've posted this question, but in case: The [pbkdf2 module](https://github.com/openldap/openldap/tree/master/contrib/slapd-modules/passwd/pbkdf2) supports this. However, AFAIK, this isn't included in Debian, but you could built it yourself.